# Margin of html element defaulting to fill width of containing div, cannot override

Tags: html, css, position, margin, margins

I'm a fairly novice web developer and I'm having a very fundamental problem that I would really appreciate some help with:

No matter what width I set any elements within a certain containing div, safari and Chrome both add extra margins that fill the width of the div. If I specify them to have 0 margins the css is overridden. For example, I have the following

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element1">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and I set this as the css:

```
.container{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin-left:7.5%;
    margin-right:7.5%;
    padding:30px;
    color:#505050;
    line-height:1.5;
    font-size:14px;
}

.element1{
    max-width:50%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

element1 has a width of 50% of the containing element, but it then has an extra margin to the right that fills up the rest of the width of the containing element. Why is this happening and how do I set this right-margin to 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in a reset stylesheet before your stylesheet to normalise all the browsers. Browsers have their own ideas about default padding and margins etc. for different elements. By resetting the stylesheet, you are making every browser start from the same position.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I realized the problem I was having was that one of the elements was floated so the containing element stopped expanding to fill it. This caused the issue that I mistakenly thought was due to the margins not changing. The answer appears to be to float the containing element as well -- gotta say this is one of the odder CSS behaviors I've seen, but apparently that's the standard. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you don't understand the concept of block level elements.

"By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do not. For information about white space, line breaks, and block formatting, please consult the section on text."

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3